# sql selecting and joining rows multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with my query selecting rows multiple times, and my left join joining rows multiple times.

The table I am querying looks something like this. The table is partitioned by wins.(this is example data)

```
+-----------+------------+------+---------+------+--+
| Player_ID |    name    | wins | matches | nrow |  |
+-----------+------------+------+---------+------+--+
|      4070 | Twilight   | 1L   | 1L      | 5L   |  |
|      4073 | Pinkie Pie | 1L   | 1L      | 3L   |  |
|      4071 | Fluttershy | 1L   | 1L      | 4L   |  |
|      4077 | jim        | 1L   | 1L      | 2L   |  |
|      4075 | mike       | 1L   | 1L      | 1L   |  |
|      4076 | sam        | 0L   | 1L      | 2L   |  |
|      4072 | Applejack  | 0L   | 1L      | 1L   |  |
|      4074 | gav        | 0L   | 1L      | 3L   |  |
+-----------+------------+------+---------+------+--+
```

and the query looks like this

```
SELECT player_standings.player_ID, matched_player.player_ID, player_standings.wins, player_standings.nrow, matched_player.nrow
FROM player_standings LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT player_ID, wins, nrow FROM player_standings
) AS matched_player ON
(matched_player.wins = player_standings.wins and matched_player.nrow % 2 = 0)
WHERE player_standings.nrow % 2 = 1;
```

matched players are selected on every second row to avoid getting duplicate values between player1 and player2 columns over all rows . I cannot achieve the same thing by using inequality operators.

the results I get look like this

```
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
| player1 | player2 | wins | player1 nrow | player2 nrow |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
|    4070 |    4071 | 1L   | 5L           | 4L           |
|    4075 |    4071 | 1L   | 1L           | 4L           |
|    4073 |    4077 | 1L   | 3L           | 2L           |
|    4074 |    4076 | 0L   | 3L           | 2L           |
|    4075 |    4077 | 1L   | 1L           | 2L           |
|    4073 |    4071 | 1L   | 3L           | 4L           |
|    4072 |    4076 | 0L   | 1L           | 2L           |
|    4070 |    4077 | 1L   | 5L           | 2L           |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

notice how there are duplicate values for player 1 and player 2.

In summary, what I want, is for player1 to have a unique value for each row. For player2 I want to have a unique value for each row, or to have the value 'null' if there are no matching rows in the query.

The result I want should look something like this

```
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
| player1 | player2 | wins | player1 nrow | player2 nrow |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
|    4070 |    4071 | 1L   | 5L           | 4L           |
|    4073 |    4077 | 1L   | 3L           | 2L           |
|    4074 |    4076 | 0L   | 3L           | 2L           |
|    4075 |    null | 1L   | 1L           | null         |
|    4072 |    null | 0L   | 1L           | null         |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what I mean by duplicates is, duplicate values across rows, not columns. For example, 4070 appears twice in the player1 column; 4071 appears 3 times in the player2 column

Comment: Update your question by adding a new table showing the desire output.  Leave the current output in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are after is this. Basically, as I understood you correctly you want to have a report where the information is displayed in two column mode. Usually this type of queries solved with the help of a window function. I used ROW_NUMBER()

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/86351/8)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE player_standings
    (player_ID int, name varchar(10), wins varchar(2), matches varchar(2), nrow varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO player_standings
    (player_ID, name, wins, matches, nrow)
VALUES
    (4070, 'Twilight', '1L', '1L', '5L'),
    (4073, 'Pinkie Pie', '1L', '1L', '3L'),
    (4071, 'Fluttershy', '1L', '1L', '4L'),
    (4077, 'jim', '1L', '1L', '2L'),
    (4075, 'mike', '1L', '1L', '1L'),
    (4076, 'sam', '0L', '1L', '2L'),
    (4072, 'Applejack', '0L', '1L', '1L'),
    (4074, 'gav', '0L', '1L', '3L')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT player_standings1.player_ID, matched_player.player_ID, 
player_standings1.wins, player_standings1.nrow, matched_player.nrow
FROM (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY wins ORDER BY player_ID) rn from player_standings ) player_standings1 LEFT JOIN 
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY wins ORDER BY player_ID) rn from player_standings ) matched_player 
ON player_standings1.wins = matched_player.wins AND player_standings1.rn = matched_player.rn+1
where player_standings1.rn%2=1
ORDER BY 3,1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/86351/8/0)**:

```
| player_id | player_id | wins | nrow |   nrow |
|-----------|-----------|------|------|--------|
|      4072 |    (null) |   0L |   1L | (null) |
|      4076 |      4074 |   0L |   2L |     3L |
|      4070 |    (null) |   1L |   5L | (null) |
|      4073 |      4071 |   1L |   3L |     4L |
|      4077 |      4075 |   1L |   2L |     1L |
```

The same query can be written with a CTE:

```
with withrn as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY wins ORDER BY player_ID) rn from player_standings)
SELECT player_standings1.player_ID, matched_player.player_ID, player_standings1.wins, player_standings1.nrow, matched_player.nrow
FROM withrn player_standings1 LEFT JOIN withrn matched_player 
ON player_standings1.wins = matched_player.wins AND player_standings1.rn = matched_player.rn+1
where player_standings1.rn%2=1
ORDER BY 3,1,2
```

Comment: Awesome work. player_standings is a view that contains a row_number under nrow. I see you have done the same thing, except you added it in to the query. Is it better practice to do it this way, or is it fine to add that column in to a view (since I guess it would be slower to add a row_number column every time I use that query.)

Comment: I would use an CTE. You have not specified what version of postgres you  have, so I decided against the CTE. With a CTE the query will look neater. The view is good as well (in fact it can be faster under some circumstances)